# How to locally setup IOTA wasp node and install wasp-cli?

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to setup a WASP Node in my local, to create a WASP Chain and a Smart Contract on
I followed the following commands to run the WASP node on my local -

```
git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp.git
cd wasp/tools/local-setup
docker-compose up
```

The above setps allowed me to run the wasp docker node on my local,
and the dashboard was accessible on: `http://localhost/wasp/dashboard/`

The further steps were to installed the wasp-cli,
and the ReadMe says to download the wasp cli from the release pages
I found this is the latest one - https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp/releases/tag/v0.3.8
But I don't understand where to download the assets ie. in which location,
and do what/run what command exactly to setup the cli?

Answer (score 2):

First download the latest release, unpack and rename:

```
wget https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp/releases/download/v0.5.1-alpha.1/wasp-cli_0.5.1-alpha.1_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz

tar xvfz wasp-cli_0.5.1-alpha.1_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz

mv wasp-cli_0.5.1-alpha.1_Linux_x86_64/ wasp-cli
```

Add the wasp-cli into the system PATH:

```bash
export PATH="/home/pavide/wasp-cli/:$PATH"
```

Now the command should be available into the whole system.